# How to install Exteme Scale on Websphere non-federated

Tags: websphere

We have a websphere cluster, but to save on licencing we are moving our dev testing servers to websphere base. However I am having issues trying to create the profiles for Extreme Scale on Websphere BASE.

I am doing the following:

```
$WAS_PATH/bin/manageprofiles.sh -create -profileName AppSrv01 -templatePath $WAS_PATH/profileTemplates/default -enableAdminSecurity true -adminUserName admin -adminPassword admin -nodeName AppSrvNode01 -serverName XXXXServ01
$WAS_PATH/bin/manageprofiles.sh -create -profileName xsSrv01 -templatePath $WAS_PATH/profileTemplates/xs_augment/default/  -nodeName xsNode01 -cellName XXXXnode01Cell
$WAS_PATH/bin/manageprofiles.sh -augment -profileName AppSrv01 -templatePath $WAS_PATH/profileTemplates/xs_augment/default
```

However when the Apps deploy I get the error that the extreme scale cannot be found. Even though it is showing under my Servers

[image]

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using eXtreme Scale 8.6.0.2 with WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.  eXtreme Scale 8.6.0.2 was released in 2013.  WebSphere 8.5.5 also was released that same year.  There may be some integration issues with eXtreme Scale 8.6.0.2 with that level of WebSphere Application Server since it was so new.  The latest eXtreme Scale release is 8.6.1 and the latest fix pack is 8.6.1.3 for that release stream.  I would recommend to use that level of eXtreme Scale or at the bare minimum to use 8.6.0.8 with the latest ifix level if you are going to stay on the 8.6.0 service stream.  Here is the recommended fixes page for eXtreme Scale:  https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27018991

Comment: I will download the newer Extreme scale today and test, thanks